# How can I get an integer output on BSD ping?

Tags: freebsd, shell

I am trying to perform a simple check on an integer value output from ping. In Linux this was working quite nicely, but the FreeBSD ping outputs a float value with percentage sign suffixed.

```
LOSS=`/sbin/ping -c 10 -W 1000 -n $IP | grep loss | awk '{print $7}'`

if [ ${LOSS} > ${LIMIT} ]; then
    # Do something here
fi
```

But since the value of ${LOSS} is a string, the comparison is failing under BSD.

Help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could alter the `awk` to split on both spaces and dots in order to pull out the integer part of the loss figure.

```
ping -c 10 1.2.3.4 | grep loss | awk '{FS = " |[\.]"} {print $7}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look on the BSDs' ping command. `man ping`  I assume you want de following:

```
#!/bin/sh

count1=0
count2=0

Ping=$(ping -s 64 10.10.24.6 -c 10 | grep packet | awk '{print $(NF-2)}') # BSD
#Ping=$(ping -s 64 10.10.24.6 -c 10 | grep packet | awk '{print $(NF-4)}')  # Linux

if [ "$Ping" == "0%" ]; then
count1=$((count1 + 1))
echo IP_addr" "UP" "
else
count2=$((count2 + 1))
echo IP_addr" "DOWN" "
fi

echo $count1 IP addresses UP and $count2 IP addresses DOW
```

In case you don't get the desired result, figure out what parameteres you need to modify in the ping command.

Hope it helps!